# JSON schema validation for enum shows same error message twice

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm submitting this JSON string:

```
{
    "companyName" : "Goog"
}
```

The schema is:

```
{
    "companyName": { 
        "type":[ "string", "null" ], 
        "description": "Companies list", 
        "required":false ,
        "maxLength": 256,
        "enum": [ "Google", "Apple" , null ]
    }
}
```

I use the Newtonsoft.Json validator function **IsValid**

```
JObject jobj= _jsonParser.ToJSonObject(jsonString);
IList<string> errMessages;
var valid = jobj.IsValid(jsonSchema, out errMessages);
```

When I validate, I get the same error message repeated twice:

```
Value "Goog" is not defined in enum. Line 34,
 position 35.,
Value "Goog" is not defined in enum. Line 34,
 position 35.
```

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing? Or is this a problem with JSON validator?

Comment: can you show us the code you are using to validate the json schema?

Comment: @JanR, I am using the Newtonsoft.Json function IsValid. Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions.IsValid(this JToken, JsonSchema, out IList<string>). This is my code: var entity = _jsonParser.ToObject(jsonEntity);

            IList<string> errMessages;

            var valid = entity.IsValid(jsonSchema, out errMessages);

Comment: When showing us code, you should put that in your question by editing it in.  Don't use comments for that.

Comment: @JeffMercado , I have made the edit to the question. I am using the Newtonsoft.Json schema validator.

Comment: @JanR Updated the question with the function I am using.

Answer (score 0):

For the error messages I received, I put it in a list and called the distinct()

```
errMessages.Distinct().ToList()
```